# Extracting between specific time lines from log file with grep and awk

Tags: awk, grep, logs

I'd like to extract all lines with between specific time, plus the filename attached with it.

Input example:

```
Dec  8 22:00:05 host kernel:
Dec  8 23:00:05 host kernel:
Dec  8 23:34:45 host kernel:
Dec  8 23:54:45 host kernel:
Dec  9 00:34:45 host kernel:
Dec  9 00:54:45 host kernel:
Dec  9 01:54:45 host kernel:
Dec  9 02:54:45 host kernel:
Dec  9 03:54:45 host kernel:
Dec  9 04:54:45 host kernel:
Dec  9 05:54:45 host kernel:
```

My Desired output :

```
Dec  8 23:00:05 host kernel:
Dec  8 23:34:45 host kernel:
Dec  8 23:54:45 host kernel:
Dec  9 00:34:45 host kernel:
Dec  9 00:54:45 host kernel:
```

Comment: Maybe you can adapt one of the answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555522/grep-particular-log-entry-greater-than-specific-time)?

Comment: Do you just want the lines to be between those particular times on those particular dates?

Answer (score 1):

How about [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference.html) ?

```
$ mlr --nidx --repifs filter -S '
    t = strptime($3,"%H:%M:%S"); 
    t > strptime("23:00","%H:%M") || t < strptime("01:00","%H:%M")
' input
Dec 8 23:00:05 hermes kernel: [<ffffffff8118a6f0>] warn_alloc_failed+0x110/0x180
Dec 8 23:34:45 hermes kernel: [<ffffffff816a204a>] __alloc_pages_slowpath+0x6b6/0x724
Dec 8 23:54:45 hermes kernel: [<ffffffff81424400>] ? misc_open+0x40/0x1c0
Dec 9 00:34:45 hermes kernel: [<ffffffff8118ec85>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x405/0x420
Dec 9 00:54:45 hermes kernel: [<ffffffff8118ec85>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x405/0x420
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, with GNU `grep`:

```
grep -e "00:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" -e "23:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" in_file > out_file
```

---

Look for de pattern `00:[<0 to five><0 to nine>]:[<0 to five><0 to nine>]`

or the pattern `23:[<0 to five><0 to nine>]:[<0 to five><0 to nine>]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I forgot something related to the my issue . I have updated my issue. Could you please help to me? Can you clarify me your grep command that you have write ?

Comment: Sorry, I just grep 23 and forgot 00:00, I'll come back.

Answer (score 0):

With perl, assuming you want to start 11pm Dec 8 and extend for 2 hours:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -lane '
    BEGIN {
        $start = Time::Piece->strptime("Dec 8 23:00:00", "%b %d %T");
        $stop = $start + 2*3600;
    }
    $t = Time::Piece->strptime("@F[0,1,2]", "%b %d %T");
    print if $start <= $t && $t <= $stop;
' file
```