# Linux count number of lines a specific word occurs in a text file based on certain date and time stamp

Tags: linux

How can i count number of lines having the word -> [com.java.Name abc] <- in a text file based on certain date and time

I tried below but showing only 1 the value. Expected there is 4 lines. It should count based on lines not word. How can i mention the date and time as well

```
grep -c '[com.java.Name abc]' server.log | wc -l
```

Below is the sample file

```
2020-06-14 13:46:10,442 INFO  [com.java.Name abc] [com.java.Name abc]
2020-06-14 13:46:20,420 INFO  [com.java.Name abc]
2020-06-14 13:47:14,410 INFO  [com.java.Name abc]
2020-06-14 13:48:12,442 INFO  [com.java.Name abc]
```

Comment: Do you know the _exact_ timestamp as it occurs in your logfile, or do you want to "look for occurence of a specific pattern somewhere between timestamp 1 and timestamp 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you are looking for a pattern which contains `[` and `]`. These have a special meaning in regular expressions, namely they are "character lists" and match any character enclosed in them. So, performing

```
grep '[com.java.Name abc]' logfile
```

would match any line containing any of the characters `a`, `b`, `c`, `e`, `j`, `m`, `o`, `v`, `N`, the space, and the period `.`, regardless of their location on the line (which likely matches every line of the log file).

You need to escape the `[` and `]`, as in

```
grep -c '\[com.java.Name abc\]' logfile
```

or - as pointed out by @terdon - use the `-F` flag:

```
grep -c -F '[com.java.Name abc]' logfile
```

If you want to look for occurences at a certain date, the mechanism depends. If you know the day, say `2020-06-14`, it could be as easy as stating

```
grep -c '^2020-06-14.*\[com.java.Name abc\]' logfile
```

If you want to search based on the full timestamp, that approach would only work if you knew the *exact* moment as it is formatted in the logfile, as in

```
grep -c '^2020-06-14 13:48:12,442.*\[com.java.Name abc\]' logfile
```

which is unlikely because then you probably wouldn't need to count the occurences in the first place. In that case, you could try to adapt some of the following answers:

- [Extracting between specific time lines from log file with grep and awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556305/extracting-between-specific-time-lines-from-log-file-with-grep-and-awk)
- [grep particular log entry greater than specific time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555522/grep-particular-log-entry-greater-than-specific-time)

Answer (score 2):

The `-c` grep option already does the count. So the result of the `grep` is a single number. Hence `wc` will of course only find one line. Just remove the `wc` altogether.

Comment: I already tried.. if i put grep -c '[com.java.Name abc]' server.log i get 20700 which not correct however when i try grep -c 'com.java.Name abc' server.log i get 4 lines. why is is like that? and how to perform based on certai ndate and time