# list filenames stored in text file with a certain timestamp

Tags: grep, ls, timestamps

I have stored a couple of file names in a text file by the name **new1.txt** in my home directory, now i'm using a loop to list all the files in the directory they are present in. I am able to write the command to perform this 
`while read in; do ls -lrt /newusr/home/logs/"$in"; done < new1.txt`

These logs were generated yesterday, what I want is to find all the files that were generated after 2pm yesterday, I tried inserting a grep statement but i think i wrote it wrong
`while read in; do ls -lrt /prdusr/rhd/prdoper/opLogDir/"$in"; done < new1.txt | grep "Dec 18 {14-23}"`. Is there anything wrong with the syntax or any other way i can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grep` to filter timestamps for a range of accepted times is not easy, as regular expressions are designed for text patterns, not numerical comparisons (see e.g. [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/555522/377345) and other, similar questions).

**In your particular case**, you could modify the statement as in

```
grep -E "Dec 18 (1[4-9]|2[0123])"
```

but note that this requires GNU `grep` and "extended regular expressions" syntax. The syntax you used would have searched for the *literal string* `{14-23}` to occur in your `ls` output line.

Also, as a general note, parsing the output of `ls` is [strongly disrecommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) as there are many pitfalls if your filenams contain unusual characters or your locale settings lead to different timestamp formats etc. The approach you chose, e.g. entirely relies on `ls`'s habit to display the timestamp as `Mon DD HH:MM` for modification times that occured in the past 1/2 year or so. It is safer to use, e.g. `find` with the `-mtime` option (possibly together with `-daystart`) instead.

Answer (score 3):

First create a reference timestamp file with the correct `mtime` timestamp:

```
touch -d 2019-12-18T14:00 timestamp
```

Then parse your file and for each file test whether the file is newer than that `timestamp` file we just created:

```bash
while IFS= read -r name; do
    if [[ /prdusr/rhd/prdoper/opLogDir/$name -nt timestamp ]]; then
        printf 'Updated: %s\n' "/prdusr/rhd/prdoper/opLogDir/$name"
    fi
done <new1.txt
```

This uses the `-nt` file test in `bash` to check the modification timestamp (note that `bash` doesn't perform this test with a sub-second accuracy).

Using POSIX tools:

```sh
touch -d 2019-12-18T14:00 timestamp

while IFS= read -r name; do
    if [ -n "$( find "/prdusr/rhd/prdoper/opLogDir/$name" -newer timestamp )" ]
    then
        printf 'Updated: %s\n' "/prdusr/rhd/prdoper/opLogDir/$name"
    fi
done <new1.txt
```

This would do the test using `find` instead, which would output the found path if the file at hand was modified after the `timestamp` file, and the shell would detect the output as a non-empty string and call `printf`.