# How to check logs greater than certain duration using grep?

Tags: grep

```
grep -lw  -e '0123456789' application.log_2023-07-*
```

I want logs greater than 2023-07-*, how do I achieve it?

Similar Question:

[grep particular log entry greater than specific time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555522/grep-particular-log-entry-greater-than-specific-time)

Comment: In your case, does greater than 2023-07-* includes July (greater and equal), or only starting from August (08)? Also, does it have to be based on the file name, or by the file's last change/modification time, regardless of the name?

Comment: includes july.  only name nothing to do with modification time. KISS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use at least two patterns (in the same line), one for 7-9 and one for 10-22.

```
application.log_2023-0[7-9]-* application.log_2023-1[0-2]-*
```

If you also want the same command to work at the next year(s), also add wildcard for the year.

```
application.log_202[4-9]-*-*
```

Comment: does [7-9] includes 7 and 9?

Comment: @achhainsan Yes, it does.  It's identical to `[789]`.